# how to print div from html to qweb report in invoice (website) ? Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

In the 'report_invoice_document' report, I added :

```
  <t t-if="report_type == 'html'">
      <div class="from_website" >
           <strong> Printed From Invoice</strong>
      </div>
  </t>
```

I want to get this div only when printing or downloding from website side .

How can I do it without modifying the content of the report generated from backend.
Any help please ?
Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `website` variable to check if the invoice report is printed from the website

> **website**
> the current website object, if any (this item can be present but None)

Try the following code:

```
<t t-if="website">
    <div class="from_website" >
        <strong> Printed From Website</strong>
    </div>
</t>
```

**Edit (Report Preview)**

You can add an extra parameter to the report URL (inside the report_pdf_preview.js file `?variable_name=`) and alter the [_render_template](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L569) function to add a new report value based on the URL parameter then use it inside the template to hide text if the user uses the report preview.

**Example:**

```
class IrActionsReport(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.actions.report'
    
    def _render_template(self, template, values=None):
        values['pdf_preview'] = request.params.get('pdf_preview')
        return super(IrActionsReport, self)._render_template(template, values=values)
```

You can hide an element like following:

```
<div t-if="not pdf_preview and website">
  From website
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this , I got same result in the 2 reports : the div is displayed from website & backend.@Kenly

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps you follow to print the invoice report from the backend and website?

Comment: I edited the post by adding images, @Kenly

Comment: I did the same and the div is only shown when I print from the website? The [website](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/uk/developer/reference/addons/reports.html#report-template) variable is always provided by the report template. How did you add the above code to the report document and did you override that variable before using it?

Comment: The problem because I'm using ReportViewer in backend (I have this module installed in my database https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/report_pdf_preview/) , any idea how to solve it ? @Kenly

Comment: You can add an extra parameter to the report URL (inside `report_pdf_preview.js` file) and alter the [_render_template](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L569) function to add a new report value based on the URL parameter then use it inside the template to hide text if the user uses the report preview.

Comment: How can change the url in report_pdf_preview.js, @Kenly

Comment: Add a the end of the URL `?variable_name=` (change variable_name to whatever you want to use inside the report template)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243849/discussion-between-k-ju-and-kenly).